# how to convert matrix3d ​into `rotateX`, `rotateY`, and `rotateZ` values?

Tags: javascript, matrix, rotation

`rotateZ: 45`, `rotateX: 10`, `rotateY: 20`

The following values ​​are converted to matrix3d

```
matrix3d(0.622467, 0.706459, 0.336824, 0, -0.696364, 0.696364, -0.173648, 0, -0.357228, -0.126462, 0.925417, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

The converted value.

How do I convert the converted value back to `rotatex`, `rotatey`, `rotatez`?

Please help me!

Comment: This might help you [Get 3D CSS rotation value from matrix3d() with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34450835/8106583)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work. :(